# Prevent images from rearranging

Tags: jquery

I have a grid of 4 images that look like this :

[image]

There's a cancel button (`.overlay-not-interested`) on hovering over each image, clicking which will replace that image with a new ajax-fetched one. The jquery for that is this :

```
$('.overlay-not-interested').on("click", function(){
    var movie=$(this).closest('.movie');
    movie.fadeOut(500, function(){
        $.get('reco_product_stream.jsp?type=replace', function(data) {
            var $a = $(data).find('a'); 
            movie.children('a').replaceWith($a);
            movie.fadeIn(500);
        });             
    }); 
});
```

The problem is that when an image fades out, the grid rearranges abruptly for a millisecond (i.e 3rs goes to the 2nd's place, 4th goes to the 3rd's place) before the new image comes. Its fine after the fetch though, but I want to prevent that jerky rearrangement from happening.

The HTML for the grid is this :

```
<div id="reco" class="span4">
    <div class="viewport">
        <ul class="overview">
            <li class="movie-group">
                <span class="movie"><a title="Sin city" class="movie-link"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></a></span>
                <span class="movie"><a title="Annie Hall" class="movie-link"><img src="images/2.jpg" /></a></span>
                <span class="movie"><a title="Madagascar 3" class="movie-link"><img src="images/3.jpg" /></a></span>
                <span class="movie"><a title="As Good As It Gets" class="movie-link"><img src="images/4.jpg" /></a></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Instead of `fade` use `opacity` animation.

```
$('.overlay-not-interested').on("click", function(){
    var movie=$(this).closest('.movie');
    movie.animate({
           opacity: 0
        }, 500, function(){
        $.get('reco_product_stream.jsp?type=replace', function(data) {
            var $a = $(data).find('a'); 
            movie.children('a').replaceWith($a);
            movie.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);
        });             
    }); 
});
```

This method will wait till the image is loaded and then it will show up. AJAX compatible. `;)`

Answer (score 0):

Set the containing elements dimensions to be the size of the front cover of the movie, and only replace its contents. That way, when you replace its children, there won't be a reflow.